# Merging(2 lists) X Coordinate List and Y Coordinate List to Get(1 list) XY Coordinate List

Tags: python

I have a list of:

```
xvalues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and a list of:

```
yvalues = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10]
```

The y-values are random thats why they are being notated as they are.

I want to merge these two lists into one list like this:

```
xyvalues = [(1,n1),(2,n2),(3,n3),(4,n4),(5,n5),(6,n6),(7,n7),(8,n8),(9,n9),(10,n10)]
```

And then plot them on top of:

```
x = numpy.linspace(0,15,100)
y = 1
plt.plot(x,y,'g')
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to zip:

```
xvalues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


yvalues = ["n1","n2","n3","n4","n5","n6","n7","n8","n9","n10"]

print(zip(xvalues,yvalues))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'n1'), (2, 'n2'), (3, 'n3'), (4, 'n4'), (5, 'n5'), (6, 'n6'), (7, 'n7'), (8, 'n8'), (9, 'n9'), (10, 'n10')]
```

Comment: If I zip the two lists, that will have the desired outcome? How would I plot a zip?

Comment: You mean `plt.plot(zip(xvalues,yvalues),'g')`?

Comment: @seeaemearohin, if that is what you want then yes it is that easy.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting. 'module' object has no attribute 'plt'. How can this be avoided/fixed.

Comment: have you `import pylab as plt` in your file?

Comment: 'module' object is not callable, is the new error after I import pylab as plt.

Comment: did you call your file pylab?

Comment: I got it, however I would like to scatter zip(xvalues, yvalues) instead of line plotting. I already have a line at y=1, what these points do is converge to 1. Obviously with 10 points, not much is going to happen but this is just the first case. The second, third, fourth, and fifth are 100,1000,10000,100000. So obviously, the convergence will get extremely close to 1.

Comment: scatter takes x and y values